# How to get an accurate count of iptables rules?

Tags: firewall, iptables

I have numerous rules in several chains in `iptables`. What is a reliable way to get the accurate count of all rules per table?

`iptables --list --line-numbers` prints something like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    cali-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* cali:Cz_u1IQiXIMmKD4c */
2    KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    cali-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* cali:wUHhoiAYhphO9Mso */
2    DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.17.6.000          /* ephemeral-1498158084 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

….
```

Getting the line count of the output does not give the correct number of rules. There are empty rows, titles and headers. Looking for a way to get the rule count only.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command in your shell:

```
iptables --list --line-numbers | sed '/^num\|^$\|^Chain/d' | wc -l
```

Description:

get list

> iptables --list --line-numbers

Ignore lines starting with *num* or *chain* and whitelines

> sed '/^num\|^$\|^Chain/d'

Count result lines

> wc -l

Comment: this takes forever a faster answer is : `iptables -n --list --line-numbers | sed '/^num\|^$\|^Chain/d' | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this script](https://github.com/cuongquach/iptables-rules-count.sh). Looks like it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
iptables-save | grep --count --fixed-strings --regexp="-A"
```

This will dump iptables rules and grep --count rules entries.